# OS is slow, giving a quite bad user experience

Tags: system

Does anyone else has their elementary os being kinda slow: to login it takes a while, to change the brightness or the volume it takes a few seconds to do so, when i click on the keyboard-settings in the settings app???
My laptop is definitely not that slow:
**Dual-Core Intel® Core™ i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
8,0 GB memory
116,1 GB storage
Linux gabriel-Aspire-A515-51 5.4.0-66-generic #74~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 5 11:17:31 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux GTK 3.22.30**

Comment: Try adding HWE kernel and ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa repository. Then remove `xorg-xserver-video-*`. This should help if it's a case of video driver issues. Usually, HD620 is playing nice out of the box though. I have Acer Swift3 with HD 620 and all is working fine.

Comment: Will try that. I'll get back to say how it went.